# Primefaces p:messages won't show first FacesMessage

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

**Prerequisites**:
 - JSF 2.1
 - Primefaces 5.2
 - Glassfish 3.1

**Story**:
I've created a p:dialog used for displaying FacesMessages on a p:messages element. This dialog is needed, because the user has to commit specific FacesMessages with an "OK"-Button before proceeding.

*Dialog*:

```
<p:outputPanel id="modalMessage">

    <p:dialog id="dlgMessageDialog" dynamic="true" style="z-index: 100"
        closable="false" widgetVar="wigVarMessageDialog" modal="true"
        appendTo="@(body)">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="messageDialogHeader"
                value="#{messageDialogBean.header}" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:outputPanel id="modalMessagePanel">

            <h:form id="messageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <p:messages id="messages" escape="false" closable="false"
                    showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                    for="#{messageDialogBean.messageDialogId}"></p:messages>

                <p:spacer height="20px"></p:spacer>

                <p:commandButton value="#{msg.btnOk}"
                    oncomplete="PF('wigVarMessageDialog').hide()" />

            </h:form>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</p:outputPanel>
```

*Bean*:

```
@Named("messageDialogBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MessageDialogBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private final String messageDialogId = "messageDialogId";
  private FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
  private String header = "test";

  public void showMessage(final String pHeader, final FacesMessage pMessage) {
    if (pMessage != null) {
        setHeader(pHeader);
        this.message = pMessage;
        show();
    }
  }

  public void showWarn(final String pHeader, final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {
    setHeader(pHeader);
    this.message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, pSummary, pDetail);
    show();
  }

  public void showInfo(final String pHeader, final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {
    setHeader(pHeader);
    this.message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, pSummary, pDetail);
    show();
  }

  public void showError(final String pHeader, final String pSummary, final String pDetail) {
    setHeader(pHeader);
    this.message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, pSummary, pDetail);
    show();
  }

  public void updateDialog() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update("mainForm:messageDialogHeader");
  }

  private void show() {
    updateDialog();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('wigVarMessageDialog').show();");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(this.messageDialogId, this.message);
  }

  public String getMessageDialogId() {
    return this.messageDialogId;
  }

  public void setHeader(final String pHeader) {
    this.header = pHeader;
  }

  public String getHeader() {
    return this.header;
  }

  public FacesMessage getLastMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }

}
```

*One of the messages which have to be commited*:

```
this.messageDialogBean.showInfo("Title", "Summary", "Detail");
```

**Problem**:
The p:messages element of the dialog does not show the message when the dialog is opened the first time. After opening and hiding it once it shows all further FacesMessages just fine.

**Question**:
So far i am useing opening and closeing the dialog once when the interface is initialized as a workarround. Does annyone know what causes this problem in the first place and also how to solve it properly?

Thanks for answers

Comment: did you try to change the place of the `<h:form>` ?!? i am 100% sure it is the problem.

Comment: You have form inside of a form? I see you update mainForm:messageDialogHeader

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed in the current HTML specifiations

Comment: @YagamiLight i tried removeing the form compleatly, but it still has the exact same behaviour. The form "mainForm" is the form of the site which opens the dialog at the moment

Comment: try to update whole dialog
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.update(":dlgMessageDialog");

Comment: I think: because your dialogue is dynamic, first time p: messeges is not rendered and will not automatically updated, so you need to update it first.

Comment: you set messageDialogId = "messageDialogId"; but it does not appear in html?!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not allowed to put a form inside of another, as stated in W3C XHTML specification, "form must not contain other form elements." visit: https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions.

So your dialog should not be inside of the main form, you have to sperate the dialog from the form, your code sould be orginsed like this :

```
<form id="mainForm" >
    <!--your main page-->
</form>

<p:dialog id="dlgMessageDialog" >
    <h:form id="messageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="messageDialogHeader"
                          value="#{messageDialogBean.header}" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:messages id="messages" escape="false" closable="false"
                    showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                    for="#{messageDialogBean.messageDialogId}"></p:messages>

        <p:spacer height="20px"></p:spacer>

        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.btnOk}"
                         oncomplete="PF('wigVarMessageDialog').hide()" />

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Another thing, you have to update the whole dialog, so when the dialog is opened the messges is automaticly updated :

```
context.update("dlgMessageDialog");
```

Comment: Already tried removeing the form and updateing the whole dialog. It didn't change anything.

Comment: try to do FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( this.messageDialogId, this.message); then updateDialog();

Comment: and about "messageDialogId" where does it appear in the html ?

Comment: messageDialogId currently doesn't exist in my xhtml because im not useing it. It is just there for future use. Once i got the dialog to working im gonna set all others to globalOnly so they wont show the few specific messages im gonna show on the dialog. Then ofc. the "for" flag of the dialog will be referencing the messageDialogId. Since it isn't referencing anything right now, it shows the messages anyways since its not global only.

Comment: Also still doesn't explain to me, why all of the messages work totally fine, except for the first one.